# Sed / Awk replace hyphen if and only field contains only hyphen

Tags: awk, sed

I want to know how to replace hyphen with BAD if and only when field contains only hyphen, please help

**Input**

```
$ cat file
90,12,15-NOV-2007,12,1,-,-,23
90,12,06-JAN-2008,12,-,52,27.46,-
```

**Output - What I tried**

```
$ sed 's/-/BAD/g' file
90,12,15BADNOVBAD2007,12,1,BAD,BAD,23
90,12,06BADJANBAD2008,12,BAD,52,27.46,BAD

$ awk 'gsub(/-/,"BAD")' file
90,12,15BADNOVBAD2007,12,1,BAD,BAD,23
90,12,06BADJANBAD2008,12,BAD,52,27.46,BAD
```

**Expected Output**

```
90,12,15-NOV-2007,12,1,BAD,BAD,23
90,12,06-JAN-2008,12,BAD,52,27.46,BAD
```

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing group.

```
sed 's/\(^\|,\)-\(,\|$\)/\1Bad\2/g' file
```

In perl,

```
perl -pe 's/(?:,|^)\K-(?=,|$)/BAD/g' file
```

`(?:,|^)` non-capturing group which matches comma or start of the line boundary. `\K` disacrds the all the previously matched characters. `-` matches the hyphen only if it's followed by comma or ed of the line boundary.

Through awk

```
 awk -F',' -v OFS="," '{for(i=0;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="-"){$i="BAD"}}}1'
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/fvLNVt)

Comment: Sed I liked can you explain (+1), awk looping is not good, unforunately `gensub` is not available

Comment: think the above sed command won't work for `,-,-,`, it's better to go with awk or go with perl.

Comment: Awk just do `sub(/^-$/,"BAD",$i)` and remove the if.

Comment: In awk, you could also drop the `sub(...)` and do `$i="BAD"`.

Comment: @JohnB ya, forget that. Thanks.